# Google Sheet Query and ImportHTML Function show numerical values as text

Tags: html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm importing some data using the formula below but the numerical values appear as =1599 (for example) and are being treated as text (ie cannot use them in a formula).Does anyone know how to substitute the "=" to "" in the table? The numerical values are in column H.

```
={QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://1234567.website.com","table",0), "where Col1 is not null",1)}
```

I tried wrapping in:

- SUBSTITUTE( ... ,"=","")
- ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE( ... , "=","")
- TO_PURE_NUMBER(

Nothing works. Is there a way to apply one of these solutions only to the columns with numerical values?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74858626/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Try `iferror()` and `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    data, 
    iferror(value(regexextract(data, "[-.\d%]+")), data)
  )( 
    importhtml("https://1234567.website.com", "table", 0) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Hmm that worked except it's pulling absolute values; so all my negative numbers are now positive. It also changes my dates to a number (no big deal) but I have some data in a column that had "PD 8.75%" and that changed it to the value 8.

Comment: Edited the answer per your new requirements. Please add those requirements to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74858626/edit) it. Also add _realistic-looking_ sample data to the question.